# Rspec test reports false positives on header verification unless browser is reset for each test

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec

At the moment I'm testing out a site that we are unable to compile (for various other reasons) so in the interim I'm checking the pages for compilation errors within the browser.

I've created a simple RSpec script (I'm a rookie!) that will open all of the pages on the site and check to ensure it can't find "Server Error in '/' Application." in the header tag.

This works, however I have to pop the browser and quit for every single page I test which makes it time consuming to run.

If I replace `before(:each) do` with `before(:all) do` in the script then I can get it to execute all the tests in the browser except when I do this it will report false positives (the pages that do have server errors in the header will still pass).

I have experimented using a wait statement after the `@driver.get("http://www.staging.example.local/examplepage.aspx")` part but cannot seem to get the syntax correct.

If anyone could help with the syntax or have a better suggestion it would be greatly appreciated.

My corresponding part of the script looks like this:

```
  before(:each) do
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
    #@driver.manage.window.maximize
    @base_url = "http://staging.environment.local"
    @accept_next_alert = true
    @verification_errors = []
  end

  after(:each) do
    @driver.quit
    @verification_errors.should == []
  end

it "should load examplepage.aspx" do
  @driver.get("http://www.staging.example.local/examplepage.aspx")
  if element_present?(:css, "h1")
  verify {(@driver.find_element(:css, "h1").text).should_not == "Server Error in '/' Application."} 
  else end
end
```